# Spark spinner trigger click

Tags: apache-flex

So i was asked to trigger up/down spinner click with the keyboard, but i cant find where to dispatch the event...

This is what i have tried:

```
var item:Object=spinner.skin;
item.incrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
item.incrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
item.incrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
item.decrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
item.decrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
item.decrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

Any ideas?

Edit:I had to make shortcuts for datagrid row swapping.

```
if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.NUMPAD_ADD){
    spnOrder.value++;
    spnOrder.incrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
}
else if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.NUMPAD_SUBTRACT){
    spnOrder.value--;
    spnOrder.decrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
}
```

The spinner has a generic handler which swaps rows on a data grid with the resulting value of the spinner, dispatching a click sounded like the cleanest solution to me.

edit2:

Click handler:

```
private function spnOrder_clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var toIndex:int=spnOrder.value;
    var index:int=grid.selectedIndex;
    if(toIndex>-1 && toIndex<list.length && index>-1 && toIndex!=index){
        if(toIndex<index)
            list.addItemAt(list.removeItemAt(index-1),index)
        else
            list.addItemAt(list.removeItemAt(index+1),index);
        grid.setFocus();
        grid.setSelectedIndex(toIndex);
    }
    else{
        grid.setFocus();
        spnOrder.value=index;
    }
}
```

Spinner:

```
<s:Spinner 
    id="spnOrder"
    value="{grid.selectedIndex}"
    skinClass="skins.SpinnerInvertedSkin"
    click="spnOrder_clickHandler(event)" />
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just increment and decrement the value and leave it at that?

Comment: I am trying to reuse code already made, instead of copy/paste it everywhere. Changing the value doesnt trigger the click handler.

Comment: You shouldn't be involved in the click handler!

Comment: its done, i could do a cleaner solution in the future, but right now, it works with a click handler...

Comment: And now you'll have to maintain that forever. If you don't fix it before something else depends on it, you'll be stuck with it.

Comment: Reading what you've written, you're probably better off listening for CHANGE and playing a click based on that. Note that in some components Adobe doesn't consider a programmatic change to be worthy of dispatching change events, so you may have to subclass Spinner to fix this or simply have the spinner value change a bindable variable and listen for changes on that.

Comment: But i cant know if it was a click or mouse down on the change event =/
The spinner is changing the value on mouse down, and it has to be on a click -.-

Comment: And i am not not trying to be negative, just trying to get that aproach.

Comment: That seems like a silly/unreasonable requirement, but it makes a good argument for just subclassing Spinner to make it do what you want. Probably it can be accomplished by simply removing the mouse down handler that connects to changing the value. You might also have to add a click handler if one is not present.

Comment: Hmm, well, that would save me from dispatching the click on the keydown handler, and i could use the change event, thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reference the incrementButton / decrementButton on the skin.  Do so on the component class.

```
var item:Object=spinner;
item.incrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
item.incrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
item.incrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
item.decrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN));
item.decrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
item.decrementButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

The events were probably dispatching properly, but no event listeners were listening on the skin instance; so no changes are made to the underlying component.

Comment: Looks like the spinner button changes to a mouse over like appearance on any of those events, still cant reach the click handler =/

Comment: I'm not sure it really helps someone to give them suggestions that encourage them in a direction of a rat's nest of unmaintainable code. No offense, Jeffrey...

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Based on the snippet and question I have no idea what direction this could send them; and have made no judgement on their code which I have not seen.  I've had situations where I wanted to simulate an event being dispatched on a component; although they are rare.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I think the best answers are the ones where you answer exactly what you're asked for and also add better solution to the problem, you don't have to forceful save everyone.
In this case, you are blindly assuming the worst.

Comment: No, not blindly... you posted code. It's _always_ a better solution to operate on the data than to try to muck around in the internals of a subcomponent of a List.

Comment: I don't understand that yet... but i can show you my code, look at the new edit

Comment: The spinner changes value with mouse down, i add the click handler to fix that.